# How to store a list of objects in memory at startup of webapi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Hi i'm new in C# development,
I want to store a List of objects in memory when I start a simple service in dotnet core with some dummy data and can be able to access them in the Controller.

```
List<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>
{
new Cat(){ Name = "Sylvester", Age=8 },
new Cat(){ Name = "Whiskers", Age=2 },
new Cat(){ Name = "Sasha", Age=14 }
};
```

Comment: We cannot understand what you want with so few informations

Comment: static List<Cat>  ?

Comment: I want to use them like a db but in memory.

Comment: Instead of a real DB I want operate with that list to add, remove or update the object in the Controller. So I'm looking for a way to do it in memory. I see something like MemoryStream for .NET Framework, but I want expose the data like a Service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In memory database in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231891/in-memory-database-in-net)

Comment: Create a static class with a static property for your list. That's simple and works. If you have an IoC container, creating a singleton is a nicer way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

A static class with a static variable will do what you want. Something like this

```
public static class MemoryCache
{
    public static List<Cat> Cats = new List<Cat>
    {
        new Cat() {Name = "Sylvester", Age = 8},
        new Cat() {Name = "Whiskers", Age = 2},
        new Cat() {Name = "Sasha", Age = 14}
    };
}
```

You can then access it from wherever you need it using something like this

```
Console.WriteLine(MemoryCache.Cats.Count);
```