# How do I create a database that's already included in to the project - C#

Tags: c#, database

Is that possible to create a database that's already included in the project and without opening the database application?

Because, I have to publish the system that I made.

Comment: Yes, [I have an example app with Sqlite](https://github.com/crowcoder/CSharpCrudGrid)

Comment: But, I'm using MSSql server

Comment: So, what do you mean by "included"? You can't embed a MSSQL database in a project, it requires a server component.

Comment: @Crowcoder what are those server components tho?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you are actually trying to figure out. You mention "opening the database application". Do you mean SQL Server Management Studio where you run queries? Do you just need to know how to connect an application to a database server?

Comment: See : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ms_sql_server/ms_sql_server_overview.htm

Answer (score 1):

I think that you might be interested by `in-memory databases`, It is treated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5231941/5873815).

You could also have a `remote database`, giving the capacity to anyone with your application and appropriate credentials to connect to it.

If you are looking for a other alternative, you could also export the `Scheme` and/or `Data` of a database to a portable `.sql` file.